# How can I remove aliases "which-command=whence" and "run-help=man"?

Tags: linux, zsh, alias

I'm running Artix Linux and using `zsh`, and these two aliases return no matter how many times I unalias them or remove them from my `aliasrc`:

```
run-help=man
which-command=whence
```

And they don't exist in any of the places I've learned aliases can be stored, including:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/zsh/zprofile                       (which simply sources /etc/profile)
/etc/bash/bashrc
/etc/bash/bashrc.d/artix.bashrc
/home/$USER/.zshrc
/home/$USER/.zprofile -> /home/$USER/.config/shell/profile
/home/$USER/.config/shell/aliasrc       (where I store my aliases)
```

`~$ zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep which-command` returns nothing.

`~$ zsh -ixc : 2>&1 | grep run-help` returns a (long) line from `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/compaudit`.

`..._rubber ruby _ruby ruby-mri _ruby run-help _run-help rup _hosts rusage _precommand...`

`zsh -o SOURCE_TRACE` returns:

```
+/home/$USER/.zshrc:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/$USER/.config/shell/aliasrc:1> <sourcetrace>
+/home/$USER/.zcompdump:1> <sourcetrace>
```

`.zcompdump` contains a lot of text, and it does include `run-help` and `which`, but not `which-command`, `which-command=whence`, or `run-help=man`.

It seems like zsh completions could be the source of this problem, but I don't know what part of its configuration does this.

Where are these aliases coming from, and how can I permanently remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aliases are part of the `zsh` distribution, and are set in a `C` language [function](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh/blob/5.9/Src/hashtable.c#L1199) in the compiled source code.

The aliases are used by `zle`, the editor used for command lines in `zsh`. In both cases, the aliases are default implementations that can be overridden with functions with more capabilities; example functions are also included in the `zsh` distribution. The documentation for [accessing online help](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Accessing-On_002dLine-Help) describes how this works for `run-help`, and the documentation for [`which-command`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-which_002dcommand-1) is also in the user contributions section of the manual.

To remove them, add the `unalias` commands to one of the `zsh` [startup files](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html), e.g. `~/.zshrc`:

```bash
unalias run-help
unalias which-command
```